# for loop occuring after a console.log even though it occures earlier in code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, geocode

when this code is written

```
var holder = [];
const compile = () =>{
    let latitude = 0;
    let longitude = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < holder.length; i++) {

        Geocode.fromAddress(holder[i].city).then(
            (response) => {
              const { lat, lng } = response.results[0].geometry.location;

                const foo = {lat, lng}

                longitude += Number(foo.lng);
                console.log(longitude)
                latitude += Number(foo.lat);
                console.log(latitude)

            },
            (error) => {
              console.error(error);
            }
          );
      } 
      console.log("lat: " + latitude)
    latitude = latitude/holder.length;
    longitude = longitude/holder.length;

    console.log("lattitude: ", latitude, " longitude: ", longitude);
}
```

the output looks like this

```
lat: 0 AddBox.js:49
lattitude:  0  longitude:  0 AddBox.js:53
-118.2436849 AddBox.js:39
34.0522342 AddBox.js:41
-192.7821738 AddBox.js:39
74.62067049999999
```

why would the console.log be printing before the for loops runs?

I'm trying to average out the longitudes and latitudes of several locations using geocode, but the code doesn't seem to be running from top to bottom

Comment: The `.then()` callback to `.fromAddress()` runs when the asynchronous request completes. The `for` loop does not (and cannot) wait for that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `async/await` to handle asynchronous operations more conveniently.

```js
const compile = async () => {
    let latitude = 0;
    let longitude = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < holder.length; i++) {
        const response = await Geocode.fromAddress(holder[i].city);
        const { lat, lng } = response.results[0].geometry.location;
        const foo = {lat, lng}
        longitude += Number(foo.lng);
        console.log(longitude)
        latitude += Number(foo.lat);
        console.log(latitude)
    } 
    console.log("lat: " + latitude)
    latitude = latitude/holder.length;
    longitude = longitude/holder.length;
    console.log("lattitude: ", latitude, " longitude: ", longitude);
};
// note: the compile function now should be awaited
```